# How can I chunk a string in JavaScript respecting words?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a large block of text and I want to split that into an array with each element being one line of up to 50 characters. If the string contains a `\r` or `\n`, I want that to be an element itself (not part of another string). I'm a bit perplexed on how to do this.

I've tried

```
lines = newVal.match(/^(\r\n|.){1,50}\b/g)
```

I've also tried underscore / lodash `_.chunk` but that ignores words obviously.
But this gives me only the first match. Please help.

Comment: do you need to preserve existing line breaks?

Comment: Yes. I need to preserve existing line breaks

Comment: Can you give us some examples of input/output?

Comment: use split() instead of match()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = lines.split(/(?=(\r\n))/g);
result.forEach(function(item,index,arr) {
  if(item.length > 50) {
    var more = item.match(/.{1,50}\b/g);
    arr[index] = more[0];
    for(var i=1; i<more.length; ++i) {
      arr.splice(index+i, 0, more[i]);      
    }
  }
});
```

This will first split the text into an array by your newlines, then go and further break up the long lines in the array, maintaining the words.

Comment: I meant the `lines` variable to mean your block of text, sorry if that was unclear, in your example it was called `newVal`.

Comment: Still.... this will not respect word boundaries. I don't want to break in the middle of a word

Comment: Is the final array stored in `arr`?

Comment: After the loop, the final split array will be found in `result`. To be clear, `arr` is referring to the same array, but it is a scoped variable declared for the purposes of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `String.prototype.split()` , `while` loop , `Array.prototype.some()` , `Array.prototype.filter()` , `String.prototype.slice()` , `Array.prototype.splice()`

```
// call `.split()` of `largeBlockOfText` with `RegExp` `/\r|\n/` 
var arr = largeBlockOfText.split(/\r|\n/);
// while `arr` has element where `.length` greater than `50`
while (arr.some(function(v) {return v.length > 50})) {
  // filter element in `arr` where element has `.length` greater than `50`
  var j = arr.filter(function(val, key) {
    return val.length > 50
  })[0]
  // get index of `j` within `arr`
  , index = arr.indexOf(j)
  // text of `j`
  , text = j
  // index to insert block of 50 characters of `text`
  , i = 1;
  while (text.length) {   
    // insert block of 50 characters from `text` at `index` + 1
    arr.splice(index + i, 0, text.slice(0, 50));
    // reset `text`
    text = text.slice(50, text.length);
    // increment `i` : `index`
    ++i;
  }
  // remove `j` , reset `i`
  arr.splice(index, 1); i = 1;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't respect word boundaries. I don't want to break in the middle of a word

Answer (score 2):

First split

```
newVal.split(/\b|(?=\n)|(?=\r)/)
```

Then join

```
.reduce(function(accum,x,i){
  if(x=="\n"
  || x=="\r"
  || (accum[accum.length-1]+x).length>50
  ){
     accum.push(x);
  } else {
     accum[accum.length-1]+=x;
  }
  return accum;
 },[])
```

I didn't handle the case of words longer than 50 characters, but that's just because it wasn't really explicit what should happen

Answer (score 1):

Here is just an example of ES6-functional approach (immutable by intention):

```
let _range = (count, step) => Array.apply(null, Array(count)).map((_, i) => (i * step));

let splitByLimit = function(limit = 10, string = '') {
  let length = string.length;

  if (length <= limit) {
    return [string];
  } else {
    let positions = _range(Math.ceil(length / limit), limit);

    return positions.map(pos => string.slice(pos, pos + limit));
  }
};

let getLines = function(string = '', limit = 10) {
  let splitted = string.split(/\r|\n/);
  let byLimit = splitByLimit.bind(null, limit);
  let flatten = (memo, item) => memo.concat(item);

  return splitted.map(byLimit).reduce(flatten, []);
};
```

[live jsbin](https://jsbin.com/rowawoj/edit?js,console).