# How to create an array from text by word count

Tags: javascript

This is a bit different from => [How can I chunk a string in JavaScript respecting words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376728/how-can-i-chunk-a-string-in-javascript-respecting-words)

I have to do this without using regex, because regex slows down my node.js apps. Appreciate if anyone will answer using javascript without regex.

I am building an ebook reader and have a text like;

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ac risus pellentesque tellus pretium blandit vitae ac odio. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur quis dignissim neque, ut aliquam arcu"

How can I create an array with specified number of word count (eg, 4) like;

textDiv = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit', 'amet consectetur adipiscing elit.', 'Phasellusac risus pellentesque tellus' ...]

Actually I intend to feed the array to turn.js

Comment: Not a duplicate, looking for suggestion without using regex.

Comment: There are answers on that question which explain how to perform the task without using regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a RegExp to get strings of 4 words each ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vLYd35/1)):

```js
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ac risus pellentesque tellus pretium blandit vitae ac odio. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur quis dignissim neque, ut aliquam arcu";

var result = text.match(/(?:\S+\s*?){4}/g);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good solution but why is it so slow?

Comment: Are you using Babel - [JS RegExp, Fast and Slow](https://medium.com/dailyjs/js-regexp-fast-and-slow-d29d6b77b06)?

Comment: Yes, I am using webpack with babel.

Comment: The article suggests that Babel's polyfill for the RegExp constructor might slow things considerably.

Answer (score -1):

Just split the text into an array:

```
  const words = text.split(" ");
```

And then take groups of four until its empty:

```
 const result = [];

 while(words.length)
   result.push(words.splice(0, 4).join(" "));
```

Comment: By looking at the code I think it will only return the 1st 4 words in the array.

Comment: @gouk no it wont